Aliens arrive to stop a hybrid child who has telekinetic powers
I've got a random memory of a science fiction film from either the late 80s or early 90s. It's a fairly sketch memory but a few key points stick out:

Aliens (that look human) travel to earth to stop an human / alien hybrid child
They get to earth by teleporting to a roof of a sky scraper (not much in the way of effects, just some smoke and lights!)
Parts are more mystical than sci-fi it feels like
The hybrid child has telekinetic powers
The final battle takes place on the sky scraper and (this is the really clear part I remember) a metal bird statue that is being levitated has a large spike shoot out of it and the statue then is flown into the main bad guy impaling him.

I'm not sure if this was a movie or something made for TV but it look fairly cheap!

Was the child male or female, can you give a possible age range of the child? Was this live-action or animated? Was it meant to be a scary sci-fi movie? or perhaps a comical sci-fi movie?

Little similar to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colonist_%28The_X-Files%29

I believe it was a female child, around 5 to 8 years of age. It was live action and more of a thriller than anything scary. A little similar to the X-Files but it had worse effects (I've got the complete X-File collection so I know it's not that!)

Is there any chance you might be talking about an episode of V (1984-1985)?

I remember something similar, so perhaps it is the same. There was a television series in the early eighties with a alien kid who lived in hiding with a human male. This man, a black guy, acts as his legal guardian and knows all about him. The kid had dark, straight hair and big blue eyes. He could stare at stuff and make them move in the air. I thought it was called "Matthew Powers", but turns up nothing...

You might be talking about the TV series V.
I the original mini-series, a hybrid girl is born, who becomes known as the 'Star Child'. At the end of the second mini-series, 'V the final battle' it is revealed she has some kind of psychic power, which she uses to help prevent the destruction of Earth.
In the following V series, the visitors return and seem quite intent on capturing the Star Child.

Sorry it's not V, I'm well versed with both the 80s and recent version.

@Rex Fair enough. It looks like you've updated the question since I answered it. Given the further details, I wouldn't have said V either.

I believe this may be the 1979 film The Visitor.  
This is the description of the film from Drafthouse Films, who currently has distribution rights:

... legendary Hollywood director/actor John Huston (The Maltese Falcon; Treasure Of The Sierra Madre) stars as an intergalactic warrior who joins a cosmic Christ figure in battle against a demonic 8-year-old girl, and her pet hawk, while the fate of the universe hangs in the balance. Multi-dimensional warfare, pre-adolescent profanity and brutal avian attacks combine to transport the viewer to a state unlike anything they've experienced... somewhere between Hell, the darkest reaches of outer space, and Atlanta, GA . The Visitor fearlessly fuses elements of The Omen, Close Encounters Of The Third Kind, The Birds, Rosemary’s Baby, The Fury and even Star Wars ...

... and user reviews on IMDB offer more details that match your description:

... an evil alien force ... named Zatteen ... impregnates a number of women, passing along his mutated genes and allowing his future offspring to possess telekinetic powers ...one woman on the planet in the present day bears the ability to fertilize Zatteen's seed ... [she] has already given birth to Katie (Paige Conner), a now eight year–old daughter ...
The movie opens with an old man on a barren otherworldly surface ... [On Earth] he's taken to the roof of a skyscraper where there are lots of people wearing identical outfits all with shaved heads carrying up large gray boxes. Later, there are white screens on the roof, behind which people's shadows move.
[Katie] seems to have power over birds ...

There are points in your description that don't match precisely (though the Visitor and his acolytes go to the roof of the skyscraper, it doesn't seem that they teleport there) and points that might match but I can't verify them doing so (most of your point 5, about the climax of the film)...  but overall, I think the similarities are too much to be coincidence.

This film popped into my head as well.  One of the main characters owns a fictional basketball team, the Atlanta Rebels.  In one of the early scenes, his daughter, the 8-year-old demon girl, prevents the opposing team from winning at the buzzer by telekinetically causing the basketball and/or backboard to explode in a shower of low-budget sparks.  Nobody seems to question how this happened, although I think one of the characters mentions in passing how strange it was.

Another point you might remember: in the opening scene on the otherworld, the sky is a composite of something like milk being poured into water, filmed from under the water.
I only remember the early scenes because the plot was developed so slowly, I had to turn it off. :)

Was it perhaps the TV series of "The Powers of Matthew Star" ? 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Powers_of_Matthew_Star
